# How to modify a List/Tile without Site Content and Structure

Tags: list, list-view, list-form, list-template, tiles

I created a list (with tiles) in 2016.  I have always performed annual modification to areas like the link location and background image.  I went in a short while ago to perform the modification and cannot find 'Site Content and Structure' under Site Settings.  After doing some research I found out it was depreciated back in Sept. 2018.

My Questions:  How do you perform modification to areas such as the background image and link location within the list (with tiles)?  I opened every option in Site Settings, along with the Settings within the specific list.

I even attempted a workaround that was suggested to access the page through _layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx behind the URL

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please a screenshot of what you want to modify? List/tile are you talking about promoted links?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Tiles, maybe try creating a new view to the list. This can be a list form which opens up the other metadata for the tiles. Make a standard view. You can change the view when its created to have whatever fields you want to show.

You can navigate to it by selecting it from the dropdown in the List ribbon under "Current View".

[image]

I created a couple extra on my own list... but the ones inside the black box I believe are the default.

[image]